# iOS - Change title for top bar in a viewcontroller that is connected to a cell in a view container

Tags: ios, uitableview, view, titlebar

So i have a main ViewController which is connected before to a navigator controller.

in my main view controller i have a ViewContainer and inside the container i have a table view (cells), now i want to connect each cell to a different View Controllers, and each of the view controllers to have a different title!!

when i make a (push) connection between a cell and a view controller, the view controller gets the title of my main view controller which contain the view container which contain the cell!!

please help, how to change the top bar title??

thank you very much.

Comment: It's not clear what your VC hierarchy is, or what your problem is.  Perhaps you can add pictures from your storyboard?

Comment: You want connect each cell to a different viewController? This is a wrong architecture. Generally you should just need one detailsViewController to which pass different data. Why you need 1 for each cell?

Comment: I'm doing it using the storyboard, have any suggestion how to make it the correct way? @MatteoGobbi

Comment: Sure: the correct way is use just one detailViewController..you connect the cell to this viewController, so each time it will be open. You need just to insert 1 cell in your tableView because it will be reused. I see that you are a newbie probably and maybe is impossible explain all if you don't have the basis. So i suggest you to read on the web or in the documentation how UITableView work, and how work using storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIViewControllers have a title property that you can edit. Add something like this:

```
[self setTitle:@"WhateverTitle"];
```

to the viewDidLoad method of your new UIViewController.

Comment: Yes it worked with the [self setTitle....], but when i tried only through the inspector it didn't. thank you very much!

Comment: To change it through the inspector you need to select the navigation item in the left hand controller list and then change the title under the item properties pane on far right.

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer if it solved your question? Thanks!